# Accessing dynamic property names in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-selectors

In a plugin I'm writing, the dev can specify options, which I'm storing and referencing like so:

```
(function( $, window) {
    $.widget("mobile.plug", $.mobile.widget, {
        options: {
            menuWidth: '25%',
            middleWidth: '25%',
            mainWidth: '25%'
            },
         some: function(){
            var self = this,
                o = self.options;

            console.log( o.menuWidth );
            }
     })
}) (jQuery,this);
```

**My Question**:
Say I want to loop through all three elements (main, menu, middle) and get the respective option value, how would I construct **o.[elem]Width** dynamically, if at all possible?

This doesn't work (ERROR: missing name after . operator):

```
// this selects panels with jqmData(panel="mid|menu|main")
var elems = $('selector');

for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++){
   var el = elems.eq(i);
   console.log( o.[el.jqmData("panel")]Width );
   }
```

Comment: Why is it so important for you to use dot notation?

Comment: @Gareth: You are right, the question is misleading. I thought I need dot-notation. I actually did not know, I could also do it with brackets []. What would be a better title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate "Width" to the "panel" result:

```
o[el.jqmData("panel") + "Width"]
```

E.g., if `el.jqmData("panel")` is "menu" you would get `o["menuWidth"]`.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because you're trying to use both forms of the object member operator.

The two forms are...

- `obj.propertyName` *dot notation*
- `obj["propertyName"]` *bracket notation*

You have `.[...]` *(using both. The dot expects a name to come after it)*

You need `[...]` *(no preceding dot)*

Then also, you want to do string concatenation to add `"Width"`

```
o[el.jqmData("panel") + "Width"]
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is bracketed notation with strings:

```
for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++){
   var el = elems.eq(i);
   console.log( o[el.jqmData("panel") + "Width"] );
   }
```

...assuming that `el.jqmData("panel")` returns `"mid"`, `"menu"`, etc.

In JavaScript, you can refer to a property with either dotted notation and a literal (`obj.foo`), or bracketed notation and a string (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, it doesn't have to be a literal string, it can be the result of an expression.